# what is the es5 equivalent of this code

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

```
function handleDeposit (accountNumber, amount) {
  type: 'DEPOSIT',
  accountNumber,
  amount
}
```

it returns undefined when invoked. I'm not sure what feature of es6 is being used here

is it equivalent to...

```
function handleDeposit (accountNumber, amount) {
  return {
    type: 'DEPOSIT',
    accountNumber: accountNumber,
    amount: amount
  }
}
```

Comment: https://babeljs.io/repl/!

Comment: This looks more like a syntax mistake than usage of any ES6 features.

Comment: const handleDeposit = (accountNumber, amount) => (
{
  type: 'DEPOSIT',
  accountNumber,
  amount
})

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap the properties in an object structure with [short hand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) as ES6 example for the given ES5 result.

```
function handleDeposit (accountNumber, amount) {
    return {
        type: 'DEPOSIT',
        accountNumber,
        amount
    };
}
```

Your given code

> ```
> function handleDeposit (accountNumber, amount) {
>      type: 'DEPOSIT',
>      accountNumber,
>      amount
> }
> ```

has no object inside, but a label `type`, some comma operators and ends with no return neither some value.

You get the standard return value of a function with `undefined`.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm not sure what feature of es6 is being used here

None. Passing the function through Babel with the es2017 preset results in nothing more than a reformating of the code.

This is just a function (which takes two arguments) containing a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label), followed by a string literal, then two arguments, each separated by [comma operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).

There is no return statement.

The function does nothing, returns nothing, and is ES5.

Comment: but comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand... so why does the method returns undefined instead of amount?

Comment: @robinsingh, without `return`, no other value than `undefined` is returned, despite the comma operator and it's last value.

Comment: @robinsingh — The comma operators cause the statement `'DEPOSIT',  accountNumber,  amount` get to get evaluated as `amount`, but the function doesn't return it.